# Having mulitple classes inside a class python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Robot.GyroController.getLatestMeasurement()
```

Is there a way to do this?
More specifically I wanted to do this:

```
robot = Robot.__init__(arguments)
latesMeasurement = robot.GyroController.getLatestMeasurement()
```

Is this valid python? And most importantly, is it possible to do so?

I need to do a LEGO competition. I can use whatever programming language that I want to and so I figured I'd write a library to get slightly better abstraction over the existent one (also to practice python as I want to get into tensorflow)

I have a class called robot. This class is  initialized with references to all the motors/sensors the robot has.

From there, I want some subclasses (or maybe something else?) that can control motors, sensors, and do some other fancy stuff.

Instead of passing robot (that contains references to motors/sensors) every time I use motors/sensors, I figured that I could do something like this.

PS. I am coming from OOP, and still learning python, so please, it is my intention to improve the question as best as I can. Please give me a chance.

Comment: What is `Robot.GyroController.getLatestMeasurement()` supposed to do? what is the job of `GyroController`? also please explain why you want to have nested classes regard your need.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Is "Robot" a class, an object, or a module? Same with GyroController -- class, object or module? What you want is doable, but it's not clear what you want.

Comment: @Kasramvd I'd like to have some clean code. I know I might be able to do this by passing `robot` every time to `GyroController` but that seems a bit of a pain. `getLatestMeasurement` gives me the angle difference between the startPos and lastPos ( I need to check if the robot rotates correctly).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean multiple class _instances_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i read, you want to have a Robot Class that has multiple Motor's class or something like that, maybe this could work as a hint on how that could be done:

```
class Motor:
    def __init__(self, motor):
         self.motor = motor

    def go_slow(self):
         self.motor.setval = 100

    def go_fast(self):
         self.motor.setval = 255

class Robot:
    def ___init___(self, reference_motor1, reference_motor2):
        self.motor1 = Motor(reference_motor1)
        self.motor2 = Motor(reference_motor1)

    def go_straight_slow():
         self.motor1.go_slow()
         self.motor2.go_slow()

    def go_straight_fast():
         self.motor1.go_fast()
         self.motor2.go_fast()
```

here's a dummy example on how your code maybe look like if you wanna do it object oriented.

**Edit:**
    assuming that you already got the class that "MotorController"

```
 class MotorController:
      def __init__(self):
          pass

      def goStraight():
          pass


 class Robot:
        def ___init___(self):
            self.motor_controllers = [] #List for storing all motors

        def add_motor_reference(self, reference):
            self.motor_controllers.append(MotorController(reference)) 
            #Appends new motors to the list

        def go_straight(self):
            for motor_controller in self.motor_controllers:
                motor_controller.goStraight()
            #Executes for the "goStraight" function on every motor in the list
```

**Edit:**
If you want to add the motors on the constructor of the class you could do something like:

```
 class Robot:
        def ___init___(self, *args):
            self.motor_controllers = [] #List for storing all motors
            for motor in args:
                self.motor_controllers.append(MotorController(motor))
            #Here every motor reference you pass will be automatically added in the list of motor controllers.
```

Comment: Will try this approach. If there are no issues I will accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, although this should work, it defeats the purpose of the library I believe. The robot class should be nice and clean. With this I'd need to add a method for anything that I'd like to do thus cluttering the robot class. I prefer having a more specific 'robot.MotorController.[allmotorstuffhere]()'.

Comment: Maybe just wrapping that specific library functionality into a class just to have prittier names?, that's what you tryng to do?

Comment: If I understand it correctly yes. I'd like the robot class to be as clear and as easy to read as possible (pretty much being generic). Then I'd like to append `.MotorController` to the var storing the robot object (So I can access all the methods regarding motors).

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do with 'robot. MotorController.[allmotorstuffhere]()', it is vague, you need to be a little more specific for me to come with a proper solution, share some library functionalities, and the desired behavior you want your class Robot to have.

Comment: Alright, for example, in motor controller I'd have `preciseMotorControl`, `steer`, `goStraight` and then every 'tool' method that aids me in doing those methods (ex. `getDegrees`, this gets how many degrees the motor has traveled)

Comment: How would you like to refer to each motor? By name? robot.motor[name]? If you really want to make it as readable as possible, perhaps you should have this done by the robot class as methods where robot class calls methonds on the motor class which includes your tool methods. Which would look like Robot.go_forward(time?), it has way more sense than calling each motor, as is a user friendly interface.

Comment: I do not want to call each motor. MotorController handles each motor on it's own. This means that if I write `var.MotorController.goStraight()`, it will fetch the Motor Objects from the `Robot` (I initialized it with those motors), and then execute some calculations and methods with those 2 motors. If I do need to take the wheel (maybe because I need to do a one time thing), I will use `preciseMotorControl(motorPort)`.

Comment: Is that a desired behavior, or is your current behavior?

Comment: That's a desired behaviour. I do not think I need help with that though. I am just trying to explain how it should be structured.

Comment: Alright, yes, it seems it could be done with a list that appends every object of MotorController in Robot and when you call a command you iter on all the objects on that list applying the desired function.

Comment: Could you write a basic example on the post?

Comment: See my two edits, in the first i define a method useful for appending new motors to your list, on the second one, i approach the posibility of having the motors added as arguments on Robot's class constructor